# Create a CosmosDB collection with shared throughput instead of using the deprecated SharedOfferThroughput

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Previously, I used to create collections by calling `CreateDocumentCollectionAsync()` and passing a `RequestOptions` parameter in which I set `SharedOfferThroughput`. It looks like this property is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.requestoptions.sharedofferthroughput?view=azure-dotnet) now, but I cannot find a good example to replace it with. I have a single Cosmos database and I want every collection to share the RU pool of the database.

Comment: If you accept an answer usually you can even upvote it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look a the new SDK: [Blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-cosmos-dotnet-sdk-version-3-0-now-in-public-preview/) or [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3).

From the blog post:

> We’ve created a new top level [CosmosClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclient?view=azure-dotnet-preview) class to replace
>   DocumentClient, and split up its methods into modular CosmosDatabase,
>   CosmosContainer, and CosmosItems classes. The new programming model
>   removes the need for UriFactory and other “noise” from the application
>   code.

Within those docs, you can find references to how to manipulate the throughput at a [Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.database.replacethroughputasync?view=azure-dotnet-preview#Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_Database_ReplaceThroughputAsync_System_Int32_Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_RequestOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) or [Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.replacethroughputasync?view=azure-dotnet-preview#Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_Container_ReplaceThroughputAsync_System_Int32_Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_RequestOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) level.

Comment: This is great, but unfortunately it's in public preview as of now.

Comment: If you're not ready to update (even though it's been around for 6+ months so I would say it's pretty stable), then you can stick to the v2 SDK and use the deprecated method that still works.

Comment: I just got v3 and tried to create a container with `await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerProperties, 100);`, but I get an error saying the minimum throughput has to be 400. I need the database to be 400 and I need to create containers at 100 RU/s each. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Looks like omitting explicit throughput in the parameters does exactly what I want!